# RPI4 Ubuntu 19.10 64bit Temperature Monitoring

Tags: 19.10, raspberrypi, temperature

I am wondering if there is a way to view the CPU temperature of the RPI4 when running Ubuntu server 19.10 64-bit. I have tried using the lm-sensors package however it seems that the CPU is not yet supported.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make lm sensors return CPU temp (it87)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748615/how-to-make-lm-sensors-return-cpu-temp-it87)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without sensors command this has worked on many Ubuntu distributions for me:

```bash
$ paste <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/type) <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp) | column -s $'\t' -t | sed 's/\(.\)..$/.\1°C/'

INT3400 Thermal  20.0°C
SEN1             57.0°C
B0D4             54.0°C
SEN2             54.0°C
SEN3             60.0°C
SEN4             65.0°C
pch_skylake      85.5°C
x86_pkg_temp     55.0°C
```

Note `pch_skylake` temperature has always been wonky on my system.

Comment: Ahh perfect! This command is working for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You may use `landscape-sysinfo`, which should come pre-installed on Ubuntu Server:

```
$ landscape-sysinfo
  System load:  1.48              Temperature:           66.7 C
  Usage of /:   8.9% of 27.91GB   Processes:             134
  Memory usage: 7%                Users logged in:       1
  Swap usage:   0%                IPv4 address for eth0: 192.168.1.191
```

It automatically runs as part of the default MOTD (message of the day) script that runs when you ssh.